# PHP code to feed JQuery Autocomplete with categories

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using autocomplete with categories with the data fetched with PHP and MySQL:

PHP code:

```
$sql ="SELECT categoria, name FROM categorias";
        $result = $pdo->query($sql);
        $rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $categorias=json_encode($rows);
        echo $categorias;
```

This is returning something like:

```
[{"categoria":"Vendas","name":"Cat1"},{"categoria":"Fornecedores","name":"Cat2"}]
```

In JQuery I have:

```
var categorias=[];
    $.ajax({
        url:"../categorias.php",
        success: function(response){
            categorias=response.split(",");
        }
});
$.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
      var that = this,
        currentCategory = "";
      $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
        if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
          ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
              currentCategory = item.category;
            }
            that._renderItemData( ul, item );
          });
        }
});
$inp.catcomplete({
    delay:0,
    source:categorias
})
```

But this isn't working. However, if I type the data directly in JS, like:

```
var categorias= [
      { label: "Vendas", category: "Cat1" },
      { label: "Fornecedores", category: "Cat2" }]
```

It works well, so how do I get the data from PHP in the correct format:

- label instead of "categoria"
- category insteald of "name"

Answer (score 0):

Update your SQL statement to use aliases:

```
"SELECT categoria AS Label, name AS Category FROM categorias"
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped getting the response in the right format. I now have: [{Label:"Vendas",Category:"Cat1"},{Label:"Fornecedores",Category:"Cat2"}]. I have included: header('Content-Type: application/json'); at the top of PHP. But although the data seems correct, the autocomplete isn't showing anything.